# How to create a single row correlogram

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to only produce a single row of a correlogram in R? For example, using the corrgram package it's quite simple to create a beautiful correlogram.

```
library(corrgram)
corrgram(iris, upper.panel=panel.pie)
```

[image]

For my purposes, all I care about is the top row, is there a simple way to produce such a figure in R?

Comment: So, you just care about correlation of other variables to 1 variable (Sepal.length)?

Comment: Discovered by chance `corrgram(iris, upper.panel=panel.pie,lower.panel = panel.txt )`. But this is absolutely no solution. You can try to write your own corrgram function based upon the original code and make appropiate changes or save the plot as a svg file and delete useless parts of the picture.